# Количество интересных пар в двух масивах

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Недавно научился такой фишке как "Найти количество пар в двух масcивов таких что их сумма равна X" и ето все за O(n + m).

Но мне попалась немного другая задача,а решить ее не смог этим методом. Кратко об условии:

Дано два масива A и B и число N. Необходимо найти количество чисел p (от 1 до N) таких, что (p div Ai) == (p mod Bj).

Ограничения:

N,Ai,Bi <= 10^5

n,m <= 200

Пример:

7 2 2
3 4
2 3

Вывод:

5

Обьяснение:

Нам подходят числа [2,3,4,5,7] потому что есть пары: (2 div 3 == 2 mod 2), (3 div 3 == 3 mod 2), (4 div 3 == 4 mod 3), (5 div 3 == 5 mod 2), (7 div 4 == 7 mod 3).

Моя попытка:

```
    #include <cstdio>
    #include <vector>
    #include <algorithm>

    using namespace std;

    int main() {
        int n, a, b;
        scanf("%d%d%d", &n, &a, &b);
        vector <int> arr1(a);
        for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
            scanf("%d", &arr1[i]);
        }
        vector <int> arr2(b);
        for (int i = 0; i < b; i++) {
            scanf("%d", &arr2[i]);
        }
        sort(arr1.begin(), arr1.end());
        sort(arr2.begin(), arr2.end());
        int total = 0;
        for (int p = 1; p <= n; p++) {
            int i = 0;
            int j = b - 1;
            while (i < a && j >= 0) {
                if (p / arr1[i] == p % arr2[j]) {
                    total++;
                    break;
                }
                else if (p / arr1[i] < p % arr2[j]) {
                    j--;
                }
                else i++;
            }
        }
        printf("%d", total);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Как бы это выразиться... то, что a > b, еще не означает, что p % a и p % b связаны каким-то соотношением... Например, 5 > 3. 5%5 < 5%3, но 6%5 > 6%3...

Comment: Вот в етом и проблемка,а решение через HashMap идёт на TimeLimit

Comment: Но первое значение - p/a - должно быть меньше b, и этим уже можно воспользоваться, чтоб отсечь лишние b. Или a :)

Comment: Кстати, упомянутая вами задача про сумму за O(n+m) - это при уже отсортированных массивах? Или вы сортировали подсчетом?

Comment: Да это уже в отсортированных.

Comment: Т.е. вообще говоря, O(n lg n + m lg m) :) Эта - что сейчас решаем - задачка где-то доступна поиграться? URL?

Comment: Есть но тестувалка украинская,но я вам все обьснил,а так если не смущает вот ссылка https://algotester.com/uk/ArchiveProblem/Display/40386

Comment: Спасибо, украинский не смущает, я из Киева :)

Comment: Да не за что,очень радует что кто то может помочь:)

Comment: Странно. Что у них там за машина? Написал программу, случайным образом создал файл с предельными объемами - у меня 0.18 секунды. У них - затык по времени! Алгоритм что-то типа примерно O(aloga + blogb + nb loga) в их обозначениях...

Comment: Странно,наверное у них там просто 1 комп на топовом железе или 2...

Comment: Ну, какие-то алгоритмы же проходят :) То, что у меня родилось - могу бросить, как основу для дальнейшей работы...

Comment: @pavel Что вы имеете в виду? У меня алгоритм явно не оптимальный, но что-то с этими остатками я и так задолбался :) Я ж ни разу не олимпиадчик...

Comment: @Harry кидайте код, вместе подумаем. задача вообще сложной не выглядит как-то...

Comment: @pavel Вот, выложил свое творчество :) Интереса ради прогнал полный перебор - вышло порядка 7-8 секунд.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Благодаря идеи Harry, дополнив фишками С++,написал рабочую программу которая заходит.
Вот она,если кому то нужно:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, m, k;
    scanf("%d %d %d",&k,&n,&m);
    vector <int> a(n);
    for (int i = 0;i < n;i++){
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
    vector <int> b(m);
    for (int i = 0;i < m;i++){
        scanf("%d", &b[i]);
    }
    vector <int> v(m);
    int pair = 0;
    for (int p = 1;p <= k;p++){
        for (int i = 0;i < m;i++){
            v[i] = p % b[i];
        }
        sort(v.begin(),v.end());
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            if (binary_search(v.begin(),v.end(),p / a[i])) {
                pair++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n", pair);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Идея - цикл для всех p от 1 до N, далее - для каждого b ищем бинарным поиском подходящий a; если находим - ура, больше ничего не надо...

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int check(int p, const vector<int>& A, const vector<int>& B)
{
    for(auto b: B)
    {
        int z = p%b;
        auto r = lower_bound(A.begin(),A.end(),p/(z+1));
        for(;r != A.end(); ++r)
        {
            int a = *r;
            if (p/a == z) return 1;
            if (a*z > p) break;
        }
    }
    return 0;

}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int n,ca,cb;
    cin >> n >> ca >> cb;
    vector<int> a(ca),b(cb);
    for(int i = 0; i < ca; ++i) cin >> a[i];
    for(int i = 0; i < cb; ++i) cin >> b[i];
    sort(a.begin(),a.end());
    sort(b.begin(),b.end());
    int count = 0;
    for(int p = 1; p <= n; ++p)
        count += check(p,a,b);
    cout << count << endl;
}
```

Comment: первый вопрос. зачем цикл в методе check? Можно же сделать lower+upper_bound и разницу между ними

Comment: @pavel Да что-то я запутался в этих делениях нацело, ну и воткнул. Он дальше 1 итерации не идет :) А в lower_ и upper_ у меня были большие подозрения, что это может не сработать. У меня опыт работы с ними небогатый :(

Comment: точно. эту задачу с конца надо делать. У нас есть остаток. Мы проходимся по массиву c делителями (!) дальше уже умножить дело техники. Сложность уменьшается до O(a*b) и можно даже не сортировать.

Comment: @pavel Перепроизнесите :) Что-то ничего не понял. У меня была мысль как-то преобразовать `a*(p mod b)`, но для меня эти остатки - темный лес...

Comment: сейчас оформлю. Идея в том, что `n div a = n mod b` например при `a=b` имеет `a` решений (для каждого диапазона с одинаковым частным подходит 1 остаток). Если `a != b` то будет похожее, у нас всего `b` остатков. Для каждого диапазона с таким частным легко подсчитать число остатков. (`a/b` и плюс один если концовка подходящая). Осталось прикрутить ограничение на N и сжать в формулу.

Comment: @pavel Так и хочется, как в анекдоте "А с кем это вы сейчас разговаривали?" :) Серьезно, я ж дискретную математику или теорию чисел никогда не учил... Почему a решений, например - не понимаю (впрочем, не понимаю даже, ищем мы n или a...) Или просто под старый новый год не соображаю, но пока ваш вариант в принципе непонятен.

Comment: кст я вот та переобразовал mod в div -->>if p / arr1[i] + (p / arr2[j]) * arr2[j] == p тогда нам подходит